# Display musical symbol (unicode) in Text component not working?

Tags: unity, unity-ui

I downloaded and specified to use a unicode font that supports musical symbols (Musica), but when I set the text value of the Text component to "" nothing is displayed? I tried using the unicode code point with \U as well. What is going wrong?

(I could not get TextMesh Pro working either with that symbol.)

Comment: I saw something about saving script in UTF-16 encoding in documentation, will try that this evening.

Comment: How have you configured your font asset in the inspector?

Comment: I have selected the font in the inspector.

Comment: What I'm asking to see is [this](https://www.dylanwolf.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/unity-text-options-font-asset-300x219.png) or [this](http://www.izayoi.co.jp/assets/img/archives/blog/20170630_unity_textmesh_pro_asset_creator.jpg)

Comment: Thank you! 
You got me on the right track. I will write what I did in an answer, maybe you can give a btter answer after.

Answer (score 1):

How I did to display it with TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI:

Followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/13215070/3021108: `ttx -t cmap Musica.ttf` to get the unicode codes in it.

I clicked on `Window > TextMeshPro > Font Asset Creator`. Then I added the codes into Font Assert by using Unicode Range (Hex).

After I had added them it turned out the range was:

```
20-7E,A0,A4,A6-A7,AC,B0-B1,B6-B7,D7,F7,2002-200D,2012-2014,2016,2022,2212,2219,25CC,2669-266F,1D000-1D0F5,1D100-1D126,1D129-1D1E8,1D200-1D245,FD158-FD159,FD173-FD17A,FD1E0-FD20F
```

The characters look very pixly right now but at least they are not empty.

I did not get it working with Text component, maybe someone else can answer how to do that.